# Why is my toilet flushing slowly and not emptying the waste from the bowl?

Tags: plumbing, toilet, drain, clog

When I flush my toilet it fills up to the rim with water. It will then drain slowly but not even a piece of toilet paper will go down the drain. I've tried plunging it and nothing is coming up like it had a clog. I plunged and flushed about 30 times. I then did the soap and hot water method. Sometimes when I pour the water in it would flush like normal just from adding the water but when I try and flush again it is doin the same thing. So I tried the soap and hot water method again and poured it slowly to not cause it to flush. I let it sit 20 min add more water and repeat about 3 times. Then when I flush it will flush normal one time and then when I try to flush it a second time and it does the same thing again. I've tried plunging with the soapy hot water in there but I cannot get it to flush normally more then once. My other toilet works fine and so do all the drains in my house. Any suggestions would be helpful

Comment: When plunging fails, the next step is generally to try snaking it. Drain snakes are pretty cheap and easy to use, although the work is a bit nasty. I don't have much experience with clogged drains though, so

Comment: Are you saying that if you pour a bucket of water in, it flushes normally?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the clog is far enough down so that, given enough time to let the water drain out, there is enough room for one flush to enter the pipes fully before hitting the clog but not for any subsequent flushes.

Like Nate suggested in the comments, your best bet is to snake it. Here is a how to: https://www.wikihow.com/Snake-a-Toilet

Answer (score 1):

Had this same experience with a rear-mounted toilet, where the plumbing line entry is on the wall instead of on the floor. The flushing power works different on rear-mounted toilet that the more popular floor mounted. Snaking and/or letting the clog sit a little like overnight etc. did help, but after several attempts, I learned the only way to keep this from happening appeared to be; to get used to hold the lever Down for a few seconds at each flush. that helped.

Answer (score 0):

I recently updated the toilet in my 1930 farm house. I have found a similar problem if I don’t hold the lever down until the tank is empty. It will flush a few times and start plugging up again. I have found running water in the sink and tub helps break up the clog , I am guessing that the old cast is catching some of the paper or waste it builds up and not a solid plug it can be removed with aggressive plunging. I figured out that the water helped the plunging action when I could hear air being sucked into the drains. Running the water gives me more pressure with the plunger and has worked well. With me and my wife holding the handle down we have not had it plug even with a house full of grand kids, see if you can get it to clear out by plunging with water running in the other drains then start holding the handle down when you flush until the tank is empty, if this doesn’t work there could be problems with roots in the lines where a auger with a cutting head may be needed, or even the pipe collapsing. I hope the water and long flush solves your problem.